# How can I find a library name of .so file?

Tags: cmake, shared-libraries, static-linking

For example, I have `libprofiler.so` file. How can I get name of this shared object like this:

```
getname /usr/lib/libprofiler.so
```

I want to do it because it is required for `CMakeLists.txt` in

```
target_link_libraries(MyProject name_of_library)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do the following steps to link an existing lib to your target:

1. Inform you which lib do you need: here profiler.
2. Build the name of the lib. CMake does not really needs this but it is worth to know: Example on Unix/Linux lib + NAME + [.so|.a] [VERSION]. Here: `libprofiler.so`.
3. In your CMakeLists.txt:

   ```
   find_library(LIB_PROFILER NAMES profiler libprofiler.so libprofiler.so.V123)
   add_executable(MyApp ${SOURCES})
   target_link_libraries(MyApp ${LIB_PROFILER})
   ```

   The code above tries to find a lib and checks the following name profiler, `libprofiler.so` and `libprofiler.so.V123`. If found, the variable `LIB_PROFILER` points to the lib file.
   Use the variable as one of the files linked to your target.

In your code, you also missed the `${}` around the variable.