# How to correctly add path to libfiles?

Tags: cmake

My project has a dependency library in `~/SimGrid/lib` directory.
How can I correctly add it to my `CMakeLists.txt`?

Now I try `link_directories(/home/whoami/SimGrid/lib)`, but it doesn't help and gives:

```
[  5%] Linking CXX executable CSim2Sim
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsimgrid
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

My full `CMakeLists.txt` is here:

```
project(CSim2Sim)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -g -O0")

set(SOURCE_FILES src/main.cpp)
add_executable(CSim2Sim ${SOURCE_FILES})

include_directories(/home/whoami/SimGrid/include)
link_directories(/home/whoami/SimGrid/lib)

target_link_libraries(CSim2Sim simgrid)
```

Comment: See [How can I find a library name of .so file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40342705/how-can-i-find-a-library-name-of-so-file/40343060#40343060)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Linux, linker expects library filename to be prefixed with "lib":

```
/home/whoami/SimGrid/lib/libsimgrid.so
```

If your library file has no such prefix, it cannot be found by the linker using *plain library name*.

As opposite, specifying **full library filename** in `target_link_libraries` call works always:

```
# Assume filename of the library is 'simgrid.so'
target_link_libraries(CSim2Sim /home/whoami/SimGrid/lib/simgrid.so)
```

In that case `link_directories()` call isn't needed.

Answer (score 1):

`link_directories` only tells CMake what directories to look inside for the libraries you want to link to, not what libraries you want to link. My suggestion would be to create a file named `SimGrid.cmake` and add the following:

```
# -*- cmake -*-

set(SIMGRID_INCLUDE_DIRS
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/SimGrid/include
    )

set(SIMGRID_LIBRARIES
    simgrid.a
    simgrid2.a # etc for the names of the actual libs you want to link
    )
```

In your `CMakeLists.txt` add `include(SimGrid)` to pull the new file in.

Then in your `CmakeLists.txt` use the new variables and `target_link_libraries` which is the function you use to tell the linker what libraries you want to link:

```
include_directories(${SIMGRID_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(CSim2Sim ${SIMGRID_LIBRARIES})
```

Of course, you could just add it all to your single `CMakeLists.txt`, but dividing it up is good practice to keep things manageable.

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -g -O0")

set(SOURCE_FILES src/main.cpp)
add_executable(CSim2Sim ${SOURCE_FILES})

link_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/SimGrid/lib)
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/SimGrid/include)

set(SIMGRID_LIBRARIES
    simgrid.a
    simgrid2.a
    )

target_link_libraries(CSim2Sim ${SIMGRID_LIBRARIES})
```

Comment: I've added your recommedations to `CMakeLists.txt`, but I have the same error.

Comment: Maybe is it due to the fact that I have `.so` file, not `.a` file?

Comment: @CinderBiscuits: With [target_link_libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/target_link_libraries.html) using **relative path** (like `simgrid.a`) to the library is *undefined behavior*. Instead, original core uses **plain library name** (`simgrid`) which have *well-defined behaviour*. Aside from additional errors (your `SimGrid.cmake` misses `include_directories` call) your approach has a little sence. If you advice additional script for library detection, it shoul be `FindSimGrid.cmake` script included with `find_package(SimGrid)`.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to find the libs your project depends on and link it to the target. Thus any absolut or relative path are not in the cmake file but detected while run of cmake.

See [How can I find a library name of .so file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40342705/how-can-i-find-a-library-name-of-so-file/40343060#40343060)