# CMake find_library is failing to find a library

Tags: android, cmake

CMake is failing to find a library and I don't know why. This is the portion of my CMakeLists.txt that is supposed to find the library:

```
set(SODIUM_DIR ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../../deps/install/libsodium/android-${ANDROID_ABI}/lib)
message(STATUS SODIUM_DIR=${SODIUM_DIR})
find_library(sodium-lib
             libsodium.a
             PATHS ${SODIUM_DIR}
             NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
```

Part of CMake's output is:

```
-- SODIUM_DIR=/Users/csimmons/Documents/repos/onedoclily/client/Android/app/../../../deps/install/libsodium/android-armeabi-v7a/lib
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
See also "/Users/csimmons/Documents/repos/onedoclily/client/Android/app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/debug/armeabi-v7a/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
sodium-lib
    linked by target "native-lib" in directory /Users/csimmons/Documents/repos/onedoclily/client/Android/app
Build command failed.
```

Running "ls" on SODIUM_DIR shows that the library is there:

```
$ ls /Users/csimmons/Documents/repos/onedoclily/client/Android/app/../../../deps/install/libsodium/android-armeabi-v7a/lib
libsodium.a libsodium.la    libsodium.so    pkgconfig
```

Comment: What is the architecture of the library? (hint: `file libsodium.a`). What is the architecture of your host? Are you cross-compiling? If you are trying to compile for a platform `foo`, but the library is built for a platform `bar`, then this error is expected indeed, even if the library is in the correct path.

Comment: The library and the binary that should link to it are both built for Android and armeabi-v7a.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that I've been able to solve the problem by using add_library and set_property instead of find_library.

```
set(SODIUM_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../../deps/install/libsodium/android-${ANDROID_ABI}/lib/libsodium.a)
add_library(sodium-lib STATIC IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET sodium-lib PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ${SODIUM_PATH})
target_link_libraries( # My code's library.
                       native-lib
                       sodium-lib
                       )
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me.  However, it's quite strange that find_library didn't work as should be. In my case, able to build but when run the exe, error threw saying not loaded library.  After changed to your solution, the exe worked as expected.

Comment: This does something completely different from find_library.  Find_library finds a library that has already been built; add_library will build a library as part of this build.

Answer (score 0):

The tag `NAMES` is missing before the list of possible names.

Fixed:

```
find_library(sodium-lib
         NAMES libsodium.a
         PATHS ${SODIUM_DIR}
         NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
```

See [How can I find a library name of .so file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40342705/how-can-i-find-a-library-name-of-so-file/40343060#40343060)

Comment: Missing *NAMES* is not an error: *NAMES* may be omited if single name is searched. See [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/find_library.html).

Answer (score 0):

There is a real bug in CMake whereby **find_library()** sometimes fails to find an existing library... when called immediately after the file in question was created.  I encountered a semi-reliable repro case for a project I was working on, using **CMake 3.13.4** on **linux kernel 4.19**.  Reproducibility of the bug was around 90%; every once in a while **find_library()** would work correctly.  Subsequent calls to CMake would always succeed when the target library was already installed.  I was able to bracket the failing **find_library()** call on each side with a successful **find_path()** which verified it as a real bug.  In the end I used the following workaround:

```
# Note: release version of libfoo.a has been installed in ${INSTALL_DIR}/release
find_library(FOO_LIBRARY_RELEASE foo
    PATHS ${INSTALL_DIR}
    PATH_SUFFIXES release
    NO_DEFAULT_PATH
)

if("${FOO_LIBRARY_RELEASE}" STREQUAL "FOO_LIBRARY_RELEASE-NOTFOUND")        
    # There is a strange bug where sometimes FOO_LIBRARY_RELEASE is not    
    # found immediately after successful install.  As a workaround we mimic
    # the behavior of find_library() by using find_path() on the library's
    # explicit filename.  Note: this is NOT a cross-platform solution.
    find_path(FOO_LIBRARY_RELEASE_PATH libfoo.a            
        PATHS ${INSTALL_DIR}
        PATH_SUFFIXES release
        NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
    set(FOO_LIBRARY_RELEASE "${FOO_LIBRARY_RELEASE_PATH}/libfoo.a")
    message(STATUS "FOO find_library() workaround:   FOO_LIBRARY_RELEASE='${FOO_LIBRARY_RELEASE}'")            
endif()
```